# MySQL: Increment value if exists, create if not (multiple criteria)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with three columns ('xCoord', 'yCoord' and 'Total'). I want to increment the Total value if the x,y coordinate pair already exists, else I want to create a new row with the new x and y values with Total = 1.

Below is my best attempt so far - running the query for the first time adds a new line (as expected), running it a second time adds a new line instead of incrementing the previously created line though? Is there a way to perform this with action with a single query?

```
INSERT
INTO  tbl_DATA_HeatmapValues (xCoord, yCoord, Total)
VALUES  (11, 22, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE  Total = Total + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should work, but you need to have a unique index. The check, if a row already exists is based on the index, not the actual data in the row. No index, no checking if it exists, therefore inserting no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` performs an update only where the insert would cause a duplicate value(s) in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, 
see this link for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Consider creating an unique index on xCoord, yCoord columns:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON tbl_DATA_HeatmapValues (xCoord, yCoord)
```

Comment: A slight variation of your code was required to make the index creation work: ` CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON tbl_DATA_HeatmapValues (xCoord, yCoord); `